# How to convert a JSON string using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I am trying to access some key/value from the JSON below:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.scheduleInformation)",
"value": [
    {
        "scheduleId": "xxxx@yyy.com",
        "availabilityView": "0000000000200022",
        "scheduleItems": [
            {
                "isPrivate": false,
                "status": "busy",
                "subject": "test",
                "location": "Réunion Microsoft Teams",
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2020-01-29T15:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "Romance Standard Time"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2020-01-29T15:30:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "Romance Standard Time"
                }
            },
            {
                "isPrivate": false,
                "status": "busy",
                "subject": "HG ",
                "location": "fgfg",
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2020-01-29T17:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "Romance Standard Time"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2020-01-29T18:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "Romance Standard Time"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I want to retrieve "dateTime" for "start" and "end" subkey.
To do that I use little LINQ code in a WPF program:

```
JObjeretrict gS = JObject.Parse(JSON);
var result = from s in gS["value"]["scheduleItems"]
              orderby s["start"]["dateTime"]
              select new 
                   { 
                    startTime = (DateTime)s["start"]["dateTime"], 
                    endTime = (DateTime)s["end"]["dateTime"]
                   };
```

But it fails with following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "scheduleItems". Int32 array index expected.
```

I already have done with another JSON file with the following LINQ to JSON:

```
 var rFMT = from m in fMT["meetingTimeSuggestions"]
                   orderby m["meetingTimeSlot"]["start"]["dateTime"]
                   select (DateTime)m["meetingTimeSlot"]["start"]["dateTime"];
```

*Above, only interested by the "start""dateTime".*
And it's OK!

**Help!**

Comment: `value` appears to be an array, so you'd need to do `gS["value"][0]["scheduleItems"]`, as the error says, it needs an integer value, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found where it has gone wrong.

```
"value":[...]
```

is an array so you either access all the array items( in this case there is only one) or in your query specify the value item in this case would be `["value"][0]`

I am not sure if value does need to be an array. Nevertheless this now works:

```
        var result = from s in gS["value"][0]["scheduleItems"]
                     orderby s["start"]["dateTime"]
                     select new
                     {
                         startTime = (DateTime)s["start"]["dateTime"],
                         endTime = (DateTime)s["end"]["dateTime"]
                     };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why the JSON string has an array with only one element for the `value` key? You can remove the brackets `[]` for the `value` key and your code should work.

If you are using a static type language, I think it's better to create nested classes and deserialize the JSON string using them. But as an alternative to your code, if you wanna use once and ignoring performance issue, a code like this should work for you:

```
// JSON: your json string value
var result = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JSON)
    .value[0].scheduleItems as IEnumerable<dynamic>)
    .Select(x => new {
        start = (DateTime)x.start.dateTime,
        end = (DateTime)x.end.dateTime
    });
```

Comment: I don't have the choice for the array for the value key. It's an answer from a MS graph API. Do you have some sample for nested classes?